# Simple way to convert an object with String member variable to single String in json serialization (Jackson)

Tags: java, json, rest, serialization, jackson

Is there a simple/out-of-the-box way to **convert an object with a single String as member variable into a single String when serialized** by `Jackson` in `JSON` format?

For example, let's say I have the following object

```
public class ContextAttributeIdentity implements Serializable {

private String attributeName;
//getters setters constructor ommitted
}
```

When the object is serialized, it gives the following json

```
    "contextAttributeIdentity": {
      "attributeName": "age"
    }
```

I would like to convert it to a single String object when serialized like shown below:

```
"attributeName": "age"
```

**My case scenario:**

```
public class Context {
  int id;
  List<ContextAttribute> contextattributes
}

public class ContextAttribute{
  ContextAttributeIdentity contextAttributeIdentity;
}

public class ContextAttributeIdentity {
 String attributeName;
}
```

When I serialize a Context object, it becomes in json format like this

```
{ 
  "id": "1",
  "contextAttributes": [
   {
    "contextAttributeIdentity": {
      "attributeName": "name"
    }
   },
   {
    "contextAttributeIdentity": {
      "attributeName": "age"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

and I would like to be shown like this

```
 { 
      "id": "1",
      "contextAttributes": [
       {
          "attributeName": "name"
       },
       {
          "attributeName": "age"
       }
     ]
    }
```

Comment: Quick question: Are you expecting the string `"attributeName": "age"` only ?? I explain mysel: you don't want something like this: `{"attributeName": "age"}` ? (See `{}` that makes the String a JSON Object) ...

Comment: Hi @CarlitosWay , yes "attributeName": "age" format would be fine

Comment: I believe that `"attributeName": "age"` is not possible, but `{"attributeName": "age"}`, yes ... that is why I'm asking ...

Comment: @CarlitosWay the second one would be ok too, please check my updates in the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ContextAttributeIdentity` is a member of some other object you can annotate it with `@JsonUnwrapped`, so like:

```
public class SomeClass {
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private ContextAttributeIdentity contextAttributeIdentity;
}
```